# Group by with condition pandas

Tags: pandas, date, filter, group-by, columnsorting

I have a dataframe with 4 columns - name, date, location, amount. My goal is to create a new column called flag. For every row I am trying to look back 52 weeks from that date and if the 52 week lag amount is greater than the current row amount then flag=1 else flag=0. If the look back date 52 weeks ago is not found in the data then it should assign the flag as 0 for that row. This comparison should happen at a group by level of name and location. Date field is in the date format.

UPDATE:
I meant, for a combination of name and location there may be multiple rows. e.g. john and CHI there are two rows. one with date 5/08/22 and one with 5/09/21 (which is 52 weeks ago). I want to compare these rows and then find out if the more recent row amount is greater than 52 weeks ago and populate the flag accordingly. I have populated the flags for demonstration of the output.

sample df:

| name | date | location | amount | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 5/08/22 | CHI | 50 | 0 |
| John | 5/09/21 | CHI | 40 | 0 |
| Mike | 4/24/22 | LAS | 30 | 1 |
| Mike | 4/25/21 | LAS | 40 | 0 |
| John | 4/25/22 | ORL | 50 | 0 |

I am currently using lambda function but its taking a long time to run. Can someone help me out.

Comment: Your lambda function could be anything. I could use my imagination and take a guess at what it is, but I don't think that'd be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
df['offset'] = df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(weeks=52)
df['calc'] = df['offset'].isin(df['date'])
df['calc'][df.calc == True]= 1
df['calc'][df.calc == False]= 0
```

Although I'm not sure what you mean by:

"and if the 52 week lag amount is greater than the current row amount", if 52 is greater than [50,40,30,40,50]?

Comment: I meant, for a combination of name and location there may be multiple rows. e.g. john and CHI there are two rows. one with date 5/08/22 and one with 5/09/21 (which is 52 weeks ago). I want to compare these rows and then find out if the more recent row amount is greater than 52 weeks ago and populate the flag accordingly. I have populated the flags for demonstration of the output.

Comment: can someone help me out here? is there any other way to accomplish this?